Set theoretic definition of terms of the untyped lambda calculus
I am trying to translate the following definition (in Agda) of intrinsically scoped terms of the untyped lambda calculus into more mathematical (in particular set theoretical) notation:
data _⊢_ : Context → Type → Set where

  `_ : ∀ {Γ}
    → Γ ∋ ★
      -----
    → Γ ⊢ ★

  ƛ_  :  ∀ {Γ}
    → Γ , ★ ⊢ ★
      ---------
    → Γ ⊢ ★

  _·_ : ∀ {Γ}
    → Γ ⊢ ★
    → Γ ⊢ ★
      ------
    → Γ ⊢ ★

Variables are represented by De Bruijn indices.
This is my current attempt:

The set of terms in context $\Gamma$ (which is just a natural
number) is denoted by $\Lambda(\Gamma)$ and is inductively generated
by the following functions:

$\textsf{var}_\Gamma : \{1, \dots, \Gamma\} \to \Lambda(\Gamma)$
$\textsf{abs}_\Gamma : \Lambda(\Gamma + 1) \to \Lambda(\Gamma)$
$\textsf{app}_\Gamma : \Lambda(\Gamma) \times \Lambda(\Gamma) \to \Lambda(\Gamma)$


I am not happy with this attempt. Here are my thoughts:

I know that for each $\Gamma$, the set $\Lambda(\Gamma)$ contains infinitely many terms, but still it seems to be wrong to define each $\Lambda(\Gamma)$ in terms of a still undefined set $\Lambda(\Gamma + 1)$. See $\textsf{abs}_\Gamma$.
It feels strange to only write down the function signatures without saying what the functions are actually "doing".
I could say that $\{1, \dots, \Gamma\} \subseteq \Lambda(\Gamma)$ and that $\textsf{var}_\Gamma$ is the inclusion map, but this would only solve a part of the problem, I think.

If someone could help me with this, it would be much appreciated.


It feels strange to only write down the function signatures without saying what the functions are actually "doing".
Do you mean a 'data constructor'?


Yes, I'm talking about the constructors. I know that they just construct the elements of the set of terms, so what they "do" is encoded in the signatures. In set theoretic terms there is a distinction though between a function signature and its definition, isn't it?
